# preload random background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with the divi theme in an http2/apache/php7.3 environment. I'm not good with jquery. I have placed a background into a section that generates the below markup

```html
    <section id="random-clip" class="et_pb_module et_pb_fullwidth_header 
    et_pb_fullwidth_header_0 et_hover_enabled 
    et_pb_section_video et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_center" 
    style="background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/media/fallback1.jpg"); 
    background-position-y: 35%;">...
    </section>
```

now I want to randomize this background and I have accomplished this using the jQuery below that is placed before closing body tags.

```
 <script>
    //random background
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var background = new Array ();
      background[0] = "/fallback1.jpg";
      background[1] = "/fallback2.jpg";
      background[2] = "/fallback3.jpg";
      var randombackground = Math.floor(Math.random() * background.length); 
      $("#random-clip.et_pb_fullwidth_header.et_pb_fullwidth_header_0").css({
'background-image': 'url(/wp-content/uploads/media' +background[randombackground] + ')',
    'background-position-y': '35%' });
    });
 </script>
```

This is working as expected but I want to improve a little the speed of this script, cause for some reason the images are called after document is load and not ready(probably due cahing/deffering/minification plugin), and this makes to download these image on the end of waterfall. Due the fact that I have a preloader/spinner that hides onload, this random script makes the spinner to rotate more than needed.. any suggestion for this? Considering that I'm in http2 I was thinking something like push preload things.
many thanks

Comment: don't run that code inside of a `jQuery(document).ready`, run it immediately after the `<section id="random-clip"></section>`. see if that solves it. Otherwise you'll have to randomize the url in your PHP (which is probably a better option anyway)

Comment: I have tried next section with no changes.
I have already tried this in php and mysql, You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240442/random-background-with-mysql-instead-of-jquery how I tried through a mysql query, but unfortunately this doesn't work if a cache my page.

Comment: You should check if there is any hook available to override any divi theme section. or check if there is any html/code block available to insert code from backend.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing client side script on ready. The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded. To avoid any delay you should write server side code to show  random image in background.

**Create array which contains all possible background images.**

```
$backgroundsArray = array('fallback1.jpg','fallback2.jpg','fallback3.jpg');   
echo '<pre>';var_dump($backgroundsArray);exit;
```

**If you var_dumb current array then you will see following output.**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'fallback1.jpg' (length=13)
  1 => string 'fallback2.jpg' (length=13)
  2 => string 'fallback3.jpg' (length=13)
```

**Pick random number between 0 to 2**

```
$RandomNumber = rand(0,2);
//$RandomNumeber will return value from 0 to 2.    
$BackgroundImage = $backgroundsArray[$RandomNumber];

<section id="random-clip" style="background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/media/".$BackgroundImage .""); background-position-y: 35%;">


</section>
```

Comment: As I said this site is build with the divi theme, so the markup of that particular section is generated by the theme. What I tried in past on server side is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240442/random-background-with-mysql-instead-of-jquery

this is a function that randomize the url of the background through a mysql query to the post content. This is working, but unfortunately if I'm caching the pages the background will not randomize until I clear the cache.

Comment: I have not worked in divi theme yet, You should keep using your approach, instead of adding preloader check if there is a way to return a default background image in above <section> this will look awkward initially.